# How to manage single feature for all site collections in multiple web applications?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, feature, farm-solution

We have a custom sharepoint solution which we are deploying in standalone environment. Now we have to deploy on farm environment where we are going to create multiple web application and hosting our different version of the product on different site collection of web applications.

I will manage 14 hive folder for css and jquery by maintaining client related folder. I will rensam the solution and change the solution id for each client.

The problem is, when I try to deploy a solution on particular site, it is throwing an error by saying 'feature is already installed.' How to manage the same feature for different clients?

Comment: are you trying say you want  to deploy different versions of same feature in single farm?

Comment: Assume, i have a feature "Base". It has few lists and one list has few items. Now i will deply n actiavte on siteA. Now i wil update the same feature with few more lists and will change teh contents of teh list which has data in previous deployment. I want to deploy this new sol to SiteB..The thing is it should not affect on siteA.. How to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

If you double-click on the feature (NameofFeature.feature), in your solution. You'll see a properties window come up - as a window that details the title, description, scope, items in solutions, and items in the feature. In the properties window, you'll see an option titled 'Always Force Install'. By default, it is set to False. You can configure that to be set to True

Comment: I am having farm environment and the same feature is being installed on other sites as well. If i change the property Always force install to true then, it will affect on other client's as well right

Comment: It won't effect any where. Its just a property which will always allow feature to install forcefully, it is already installed.

Comment: Hi..Suppose, my feature name is kkk and it is installed on a site hello.com..now i am going to create one more web app and site , there i will deploy the solution on that site. but during this time, since feature has allo force install, will it affect on first site?

Comment: No it will not effect until it is different web application.

Comment: ok thankew . I will try now

Answer (score 0):

You can add that site collection feature in separate wsp and deploy it globally(on all web application).

So other client related features you can add in individual wsps.

The error you are getting is because you are trying to install/activate feature again with every wep.